# Hide / rewrite download link

Tags: url-rewriting

I want to hide the actual path of my downloads that look like this

> http://my.wordpresssite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/example.pdf

and instead get something like this:

> http://my.wordpresssite.com/downloads/example.pdf

I guess I have to do this by rewriting, but I am really not comfortable with that.
Could somebody suggest a solution to my problem?

Comment: [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin "Download Monitor" I use it and works great.

You could also set custom configuration in your wp-config.php file to use a different directory.   Depends on whether or not you want to just hide wp-content as the directory or actually completely change it.

Comment: Thank you. Download Monitor looks good but is not really what i searched for.
I just want to hide the directory, not change it.